# Use Port value in Post-SQL of Source Qualifier

Tags: informatica

How can i use value of Port in the Post-SQL of Source Qualifier ?

[Here is my Source qualifier. Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HDuj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The Post-SQL is executed after ALL the source rows have been processed. Therefore it's not possible to refer to processing-time values for each row.

Perhaps a subquery would help you to refer the required USR_ID? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Some details would help.